# Airwatch Catalog and Airwatch Tunnen URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, tunnel, airwatch

I would like to check from my app if the airwatch tunnel is installed.  Does anyone know if there is a URL scheme that I can use?  I have a bundle Id but that's not useful to verify if tunnel is installed.

I am also prompting users to update their app if they have a older version. If user confirms then I would like to open Airwatch catalog with my app preselected.  I need URL scheme for airwatch catalog as well.  Does anyone have this info as well?

Thank you in advance for your help,
AJ

Answer (score 1):

The URL Scheme for Airwatch tunnel app is awtunnelapp://

No answer on the URL Scheme for Airwatch catalog yet.

Answer (score 0):

The AirWatch Catalog is a simple web link.

You don't need a URL Scheme, just open a new browser tab pointing to that URL.
The URL will look like:
https://YOUR_ORGANIZATION_AW_URL/Catalog/ViewCatalog/LONG_STRING_OF_CHARS_AND_NUMBERS/Android

The first part of the URL is the same you use to login to your AirWatch administartoor console, something like:
https://YOUR_ORGANIZATION_AW_URL/AirWatch/Login